# Fetch Data From DB Using Defined Criteria in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two databases named `users` and `calls.`

**Calls table**

```php
<?php

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('calls', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('terminal_id', 20);
        $table->text('terminal_name', 100);
        $table->text('fault_description');
        $table->string('call_status', 10)->default('New call');
        $table->string('pending_on', 20)->nullable();
        $table->text('closed_on', 20)->nullable();
        $table->text('closed_by', 50)->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**CallsController**

```
public function index()
{
    $calls = Call::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); 

    return view('pages.newCall')->with('calls', $calls); 
}

public function viewCall($id) { 
    $calls = Call::find($id);

    return view('pages.viewCall')->with('calls', $calls);
}
```

Currently, the CallsController is returning all the rows in the `calls` table, but I want it to return only the rows that have the property 'New call' on the `call_status` column in the `calls table.` How do I do this from the CallsController?

Comment: `$calls = Call::where('call_status', 'New call')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: thanks ...problem solved

Comment: but what if the column `call_status` does not have any value, how do I reference it in `$calls = Call::where('call_status', 'New call')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`   i.e removing the value `New call`

Comment: You could do `where('call_status', '!=', 'New call')` to get the rows where the call status is not New call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rows which have

1.`call_status` equal to 'New Call' :

`$calls = Call::where('call_status', 'New call')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

2.`call_status` not equal to 'New Call' :

`$calls = Call::where('call_status', '<>', 'New call')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

You could use `!=` in place of `<>` above.

3.`call_status` equal to `NULL` (Empty) :

`$calls = Call::whereNull('call_status')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

4.`call_status` equal to 'New Call' or `NULL` :

`$calls = Call::where('call_status', 'New call')->orWhereNull('call_status')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

Laravel has an ORM which is [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) and it uses a query builder named as [Fluent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries). For more on query building check official doc.

Comment: Number two is throwing a `Syntax error or access violation` error. So, used         
 `$calls = Call::where('call_status', '<>', 'New call')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`  instead of `$calls = Call::whereNull('call_status', '<>', 'New call')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`